# MP3 player music manager

Tags: macos, mp3-player

I am looking for a free program that runs on OS X that is similar to iTunes, but for MP3 players. Any suggestions?

UPDATE: I have used Coby Media Manager. It doesn't work for me because it won't keep the artists, albums, etc.

Comment: Similar to iTunes in which way(s)? http://superuser.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: In that you can manage the songs' artists, albums, etc...

Comment: "Manage" them how?  Rename, Sort, Tag, Catalogue, Rate, Download, Buy, Send to Device(s)?   All of these, none of these, more than these? :)  Which MP3 player(s)?

Comment: All of those, except for Buy and Download. The MP3 player that I'm using is a Coby MP-620. Actually, several of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest Songbird:

http://getsongbird.com/

It's very much like iTunes except that it's OpenSource (based on Firefox). There are also some additional features like browsing and downloading the Web for MP3s. And you can even extend its functionality with plugins.

Comment: Thanks so much. This was exactly what I was looking for. Especially the ability to mount the MP3 player and manage it like iTunes. Thanks you SOOOO much!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you are speaking about a program and the word alternative is in the same sentence, check out www.alternativeto.net. They have a huge database of all kinds of programs and filter capabilities. You can look and find which applications are a decent alternative to a program that you're looking at.

[iTunes Alternatives](http://alternativeto.net/software/itunes/?profile=mac&platform=mac)